# add managed C++ to a C# GUI

Tags: .net, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, managed

The new Visual Studio 2012 has removed the Windows Forms Application (WFA) as a Template. The reason for this has been stated by MS to be that VC++ is not the best way to do a GUI. So for maximum performance and portability, I would like to use C++ for the number-crunching and a C# for the GUI.

Since I am starting from scratch, I see no reason not to use C++/CLI for the C++ development – so all the C++ will be in managed C++. I understand that I can use a C++ DLL, but I would rather not.

I can add a C++/CLI project to a solution that also includes a C# WFA project. I can the run the C++/CLI project to get all the C++ working correctly. But I am puzzled over the best way to give the C# project access to the C++/CLI classes. When I "add reference" to the C# project, it lets me add the C++/CLI project as a reference. But how do I add in a class defined in the C++ to the C# code?

Comment: I'll be honest, if you are starting from scratch... do it all in C#.

Comment: The point of C++/CLI is to make it easy to interop with unmanaged C++ code.  Writing only *ref classes* in C++/CLI defeats the purpose, it generates the exact same code as C#.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to specifically make a managed-class; i.e.

```
ref class Foo
{
    String ^managedString; 
};
```

and the public variables must also be managed types;

[See](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI)

If you add the c++/cli class library as a reference in your c# project, you'll be able to see the class in the namespace and use them like any other class.